# Jquery windows location doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, location

```
$(function(){
    $('#sn').bind('keypress',function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == "13")    
        {
            alert("12345");
            window.location.href="yahoo.com";
        }
    });
});
```

this is for press enter in input to go to another page ..
alert is working just fine , it just doesn't go to another page , window.location.href is not working ..

fixed .. the problem is i have `<from></from>`, after i remove it, it working ........

Answer (score 2):

Provide a valid URL

```
 window.location.href="http://yahoo.com";
                       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href="http://yahoo.com";
```

**you can use this code for jquery**

Comment: it's not about the url

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
Location:
<input id="sn" type="text">
```

JQuery/JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $('#sn').bind('keypress', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == "13") {
            alert("12345");
            $(location).attr('href','http://google.com');
            //window.location = 'http://google.com';
        }
    });
});
```